# Как вывести трёхмерный массив, категории, подкатегории, под подкатегории?? PHP

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

Пример беру c интернет магазинf allo.ua

Есть кнопка "Каталог товаров", по нажатию на которую выскакивают категории, подкатегории и под подкатегории.
Как вывести с базы данных трёхмерный массив ??

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот моя база, я её склеил:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так же и как вообще должен выглядеть этот массив?
P.S. Я начинающий программист.

Comment: Попробуйте функцию `array_walk_recursive` для рекурсивного прохода по всем элементам массива. Документация по функции: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk-recursive.php,

Comment: 1. Сделать внятную структуру таблицы.
2. Использовать модель Аdjacency list, Matherialized Path или Nested Set.